# Setting up eclipse-error with Java Builder

Tags: java, eclipse

I wanted to get into programming but I'm having problems with starting my first project in Eclipse, whenever I try to make a new project I get this error: Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'test'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

I've tried reinstalling eclipse and getting new jdk's but nothing seems to fix it

Comment: Have you tried installing older versions of eclipse too or did you reinstall only the same version again?

Comment: What version of Eclipse? Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.